# Node export module imported node as another node numbers

Tags: nodes

I used [Node Export module](https://www.drupal.org/project/node_export) to export my nodes.

I exported 3 articles that are node/1, node/2 and node3.

While I imported it into another site, the node became node/4, node/5 and node6.

How do I make it imported as the same node number.

If there is already have that node, it will override it.

***Drupal 6***

Settings:

**Node export**

When importing a node that already exists: Create a new revision of the existing node

***UUID***

Automatic UUID generation for taxonomy:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't, and you shouldn't.

Node Export requires UUID for a reason, and that reason is decoupling database identifier of a node (`nid`) from it's logical identifier and address. These are supposed to be defined by UUID now, so if you are using UUID module and still have addresses like http://example.com/node/1 then your site is not using modules in a way they are designed to work.

Also, as Node Export project page says, if you need anything fancy on import, you should export in Feeds format, and use Feeds for import. I believe that updating existing nodes is a case where it would be recommended approach.

Comment: How do I export in Feeds format and use Feeds for import?